# How to make this more clean

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a big part of code like this that iterate trough an array

```
void GetSpawnablePosition() {
    Vector2[] coordX = { Vector2.up, Vector2.down };
    Vector2[] coordY = { Vector2.left, Vector2.right };

    for (int i = 0; i < coordY.Length; i++)
    {
        Vector2[] newArray = new Vector2[enemyGrid.grid[0].Length - 2];

        if (coordY[i] == Vector2.left)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < enemyGrid.grid[0].Length - 2; j++)
            {
                newArray[j] = new Vector2(0, j+1);
            }
        }

        if (coordY[i] == Vector2.right)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < enemyGrid.grid[0].Length - 2; j++)
            {
                newArray[j] = new Vector2(enemyGrid.grid[0].Length - 1, j + 1);
            }
        }
        spawnablePosition.Add(coordY[i], newArray);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < coordY.Length; i++)
    {
        Vector2[] newArray = new Vector2[enemyGrid.grid.Length - 1];

        if (coordX[i] == Vector2.down)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= enemyGrid.grid.Length - 2; j++)
            {
                newArray[j] = new Vector2(j+1,0);
            }
        }
        if (coordX[i] == Vector2.up)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= enemyGrid.grid.Length - 2; j++)
            {
                newArray[j] = new Vector2(j + 1, enemyGrid.grid[0].Length - 1);
            }
        }

        spawnablePosition.Add(coordX[i], newArray);
    }
}
```

The snippet is supposed to take the index x and y of a grid

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBJ1T.png]

and

put it in a dictionary like this

```
Vector2.up => [[0][1],[0][2],[0][3],[0][4],[0][5]]
Vector2.left=> [[1][0],[2][0],[3][0],[4][0],[5][0]]
Vector2.right=> [[1][6],[2][6],[3][6],[4][6],[5][6]]
Vector2.down=> [[6][1],[6][2],[6][3],[6][4],[6][5]]
```

I tried to refactor it to make it smaller or more clear, but really, I honestly can't find a good solution that make that big thing smaller.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Sorry It is in C#

Comment: Could you plz explain what this snippet suppose to do?

Comment: @Sane sorry, it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var yLength = enemyGrid.grid[0].Length;
var xLength = enemyGrid.grid.Length;

spawnablePosition.Add(Vector2.left,  Enumerable.Range(1, yLength).Select(y => new Vector2(0, y)).ToArray());            
spawnablePosition.Add(Vector2.right, Enumerable.Range(1, yLength).Select(y => new Vector2(xLength - 1, y)).ToArray());            
spawnablePosition.Add(Vector2.up,    Enumerable.Range(1, xLength).Select(x => new Vector2(x, 0)).ToArray());            
spawnablePosition.Add(Vector2.down,  Enumerable.Range(1, xLength).Select(x => new Vector2(x, yLength - 1)).ToArray());
```

Ensure that I don't mess with corresponding array lengths.

Comment: That's looks nice, I have to watch how you made it ! thanks